# using RxJs forkJoin to merge multiple api calls into single output array

Tags: angular, rxjs

Let's say I have 4 API calls. In this case, each of the 4 calls return the same data structure so I don't need to manipulate the return types. They each return an array of objects. I'd like to call them all, but combine them into on output array. I tried combining `forkJoin` with `.concat(`) but that didn't do what I expected (it put them inside of smaller arrays).

```
forkJoin([
  this.service.getData('something', 'somethingelse'),
  this.service.getData('something1', 'somethingelse2')
].concat()).subscribe(data => console.log(data))
```

Comment: Let me check if I understand... each call gives you something like [{a:1 b:1}, {a:2,b:2}] and [{a:3 b:3}, {a:4,b:4}]... and you want [{a:1 b:1}, {a:2,b:2}, {a:3 b:3}, {a:4,b:4}] as the final output?

Comment: yes. One array that takes all the objects of every inner array and puts them into a singular array output. I can use forkJoin with the dictionary syntax and convert each return Object to an array, but that seems unnecessary given all RxJs can do. I just don't know which operator to use in which succession.

Comment: Well.. what if you just do this: forkJoin([
  this.service.getData('something', 'somethingelse'),
  this.service.getData('something1', 'somethingelse2')
]).subscribe(data => console.log(data[0].concat(data[1])))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following implementation: (concating the arrays is performed once data has been returned)

```
forkJoin([
  this.service.getData('something', 'somethingelse'),
  this.service.getData('something1', 'somethingelse2')
])
.pipe(
  map(x => x.reduce((arr, curr) => [...arr,...curr]))
)
.subscribe(data => console.log(data))
```

Or using [ES2019 flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

```
forkJoin([
  this.service.getData('something', 'somethingelse'),
  this.service.getData('something1', 'somethingelse2')
])
.pipe(
  map(x => x.flat())
)
.subscribe(data => console.log(data))
```